# How do i send a POST request to a link in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, post, request

I am trying to send a POST request to a link as its written in weGWRGWRG documentation, i did it with postman and in WEGWegw but i am not able to find out how to do it in wegwEGWEGWG.
**To WegweGEG an Event**
Make a POwegwG ST or EWgwE GWgwegweb request to:

```
url = 'https://kajglakerjglekarjglkearjg'
```

i did it in  weGWe gw using `aregerajkgearkgnkjernvkjeangkjnearhl)`
But i wanted to do in normal javascript tried but not able to figure out.

Comment: Take a look at [Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Fetch API in JavaScript (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

See Example Below:

```
fetch('https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/notifier/with/key/hereGoesMyKey', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({foo: 'bar'})
}).then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => console.log(res));
```

Comment: I would also add that this syntax can be shorted using  async/await